# Access to directory

Tags: permissions

Let say, I have two directories `bob` and `public`.

`public` is a subfolder of `bob`.

`bob` has to have rights 770, the owner is `bob`, group the same.

`public` has 777, the owner and group the same.

```
bob bob:bob 770
|--public bob:bob 777
...
```

Can other users get access to files of `public` and how?

Links to articles and examples are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link, 
I hope it may somewhat helpful. [link](http://www.firewall.cx/linux-knowledgebase-tutorials/introduction-to-linux/299-linux-file-folder-permissions.html)

Comment: Link only answers tend to become removed as links tend to rot over time. Please add relevant parts of the answer to the answer (with credits)

Comment: My bad, roger that.